# Why a customization returns the same instance when applied on two different properties?

Tags: c#, nunit, autofixture

I'm encountering this strange behavior on AutoFixture 3.50.7 and 4.0 (Nunit 3.7) :

When I generate an object containing two properties of the same type using the vanilla `Fixture` object, the test passes.

When I apply this (admittedly dummy) customization, the test fails. The generated lists are in fact the same instance.

What is happening ?

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void Succeeds()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();

        var container = fixture.Create<Container>();

        ReferenceEquals(container.Content1.Strings, container.Content2.Strings).Should().BeFalse();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Fails()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new TestContentCustomization());

        var container = fixture.Create<Container>();

        ReferenceEquals(container.Content1.Strings, container.Content2.Strings).Should().BeFalse();
    }
}

public class TestContentCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<Content>(c => c
            .With(x => x.Strings, new List<string>()));
    }
}

public class Container
{
    public Content Content1 { get; set; }
    public Content Content2 { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public IList<string> Strings { get; set; }
}
```

The test also fails if I ask AutoFixture to generate `fixture.CreateMany<string>(3).ToList()` instead of `new List<string>()` but of course, this time the list contains 3 different strings.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the `ReferenceEquals` in the `Fails` test method, what are the values of `container.Content1.Strings` and `container.Content2.Strings`

Comment: @Hackerman In the passing test, they contain 3 different strings each, as AF is supposed to do by default when generating lists. In the failing test, they obviously contain nothing (being both a `new List<Content>()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Customize<T>` API may be confusing, which is all my fault, but the delegates inside only run once, when you're done defining the customization. I understand why using delegates looks like deferred execution, but it isn't; it's a DSL. This sometimes causes confusion, which is an indication that it should have been designed differently, but now, ten years later, this is the API we have.

The customization in the OP is equivalent to doing this:

```
public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
{
    var strings = new List<string>();
    fixture.Customize<Content>(c => c
        .With(x => x.Strings, strings));
}
```

The `Customize(IFixture)` method only runs once per fixture. Notice that the arguments to `With` are made up of a lambda expression, and an object. The second argument is just an object, and since C# is eagerly evaluated, even if you put a method call there, that method call evaluates before `With` is called.

What this customization does, then, is to create an empty list of strings (or, if you use `CreateMany`, a populated list of strings), and register `Content` such that, every time a `Content` object is created, its `Strings` property is assigned that particular object.

To work around the problem, you could do something like this:

```
public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
{
    fixture.Customize<Content>(c => c
        .Without(x => x.Strings)
        .Do(x =>
        {
            x.Strings = fixture.CreateMany<string>().ToList();
        }));
}
```

The `Do` method gives you true deferred execution, but (IIRC) the order in which it executes isn't strictly defined, so you should also use `.Without(x => x.Strings)` to ensure that AutoFixture doesn't overwrite the effects of the `Do` block.

This passes both tests.

All that said, you should [avoid writable collection properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections):

> **DO NOT** provide settable collection properties.

If you follow the official Microsoft design guidelines, AutoFixture tends to work better for you.

Comment: Thanks, this makes things clear. I couldn't agree more on not providing settable collections, struggling with historical code here. Should be done someday. Thanks !

Comment: BTW, we [are going](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/708) to add `With()` method overload taking delegate as there are different scenarios when that might be handy. Therefore, if you are forced to have writable collections (e.g. because your type is a DTO), you'll have the better AutoFixture's API for that.